# Is there a Linux command to replicate/replace the "banner" command?

Tags: linux, shell, command

I am writing a script on Red Hat Linux (I forget the version) that needs a header, but the `banner` command is not there for me to use and I won't be able to get it installed. I read via Google that it may well have been deprecated.

So is there a new version of the command that produces similar results, or a way I can replicate the command, or even just temporarily change the script output so that characters are a different size?

I've tried looking at stty but we don't access via xterm, we log in directly via putty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its simplest form, 'banner' is less than a few pages of code (e.g. [this one](http://www.bsdlover.cn/study/UnixTree/MiniUnix/usr/source/s1/banner.c.html)).  Perhaps you could just compile and run it from your home directory?

Comment: Sweet :) That worked..although that source's first include didn't work on initial compile, I had to Google the error: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' which lead me to add the following line: #include <stdlib.h>
Also the first time I've ever compiled a C program !!!

Comment: That doesn't help. The page you are pointing to is in Chinese (or some other Asian language).

Comment: It looks as though the original link has gone away.  Try googling 'banner.c' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use some web site, for example http://patorjk.com/software/taag/.
If you need it frequently you can create a script to scrap the result.

BTW, `stty` has nothing to do with your problem, I don't know why you mentioned it.

Comment: I mentioned stty as it allows me to get and set terminal settings and I thought maybe there was a text size related one in there